# ostringstream gets wrong int value after incrementation [c++]

Tags: c++, stringstream, ostringstream

This is part of my code:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    tab[i]=new char[80];
    oss.str("");
    oss<<"line number: <<i;
    temp=oss.str();
    tab[i]=(char*)temp.c_str();
}
```

and when I print the tab, the result is in turns 8 and 9. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure?  As is this shouldn't even compile.  Please post an [mcve]

Comment: `(char*)temp.c_str()` bad idea! Modifying `tab[i][x]` now invokes undefined behavior. Also you're leaking the `new`ed array just 4 lines below its allocation…

Comment: If by `tab[i]=(char*)temp.c_str();` you meant to copy the contents of `temp` to `tab[i]`, that doesn't do it; you're simply repointing the pointer. You need to use `strncpy`, or better yet, `std::string` in the first place.

Comment: Temp is a string object. I used char arrays instead of strings, because it is just an excercise to practise arrays and pointers. How can I assign c-string to a char* in other way?

Comment: You probably meant `strcpy(tab[i], temp.c_str());` . As you have it, `tab[i]` points at the internally managed string of `temp`, so later on when you reassign `temp` (next loop iteration), the previous `tab[i]` becomes a dangling pointer

Comment: You are right. The assumption by ostringstream is correct. The problem concerned thic casting. Thans!

Answer (score 2):

Taking a bunch of comments and consolidating (Why are you commentators not answering instead?):

What you are actually doing there is changing the pointer value of `tab[i]` from your allocated memory to the internal string of `temp`. Which is a bad idea because `temp` will free that memory as soon as it is destructed.

You don't need `temp` at all, as far as I can see.

The C way to fix this is to use `strcpy(tab[i], oss.str().c_str())` which will copy the characters one by one. Note that your current code does a `new char[80]` so if your string is longer than 79 characters it will overflow. If you must use a `new`'d buffer, do it with something like `new char[oss.str().size() + 1]`

The C++ way to fix this is to use an array of `std::string` instead of an array of `char*`. Then you could just assign, like `tab[i] = oss.str()` and it would copy it properly. It would also clean up the memory used when the array goes out of scope, as your code right now doesn't do.